# Having trouble connecting to shipstation's api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm having a problem getting data from shipstation's api. I can see that the data is being pulled under the network and preview tab. But when I try to pass 'data' into the console, I get a parser error message. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
var URL = 'http://ssapi.shipstation.com/carriers/';

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: URL,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=\"utf-8\"",
           xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
           dataType: 'json', 
           success: function (data) {

           var output = JSON.parse(data);

           console.log('success ' + data + " parsed: " + output);

           $('#results').append('<p>' + output + '</p>');
           },

          // Display errors if any.
          error: function(req, err){ console.log('Error Type: ' + err); }

          });
```

[Network Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yr4A.png)

[Console error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVyV0.png)

Comment: Hi, it is considered nice to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: But it didn't help me. I'm still having trouble. :(

Answer (score 3):

Your `dataType: 'json',` specifies that browser will automatically parse response as JSON. So your `JSON.parse(data)` tries to decode decoded json.

Also `console.log('success ' + data + " parsed: " + output);` possible will be `success [object Object] parsed: [object Object]` (or some other variation when concatenating string and object). Use `console.log('success ', data, " parsed: ", output);` to output objects properly

Comment: I see, so I should remove the dataType: object,right? Cause I tried adding dataType: 'script' and in my console it an undefined result.

Comment: Better remove `JSON.parse` part